# Where to put persistence.xml in gwt maven MultiModule project?

Tags: maven, gwt, persistence

I have project with one `parent` maven module and three submodules:

- `server`
- `shared`
- `web`

Here is main project (aka `parent`) pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.derp</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>shared</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tomcat.webport>8082</tomcat.webport>
        <tomcat.ajpport>8182</tomcat.ajpport>
        <tomcat.context>/parent</tomcat.context>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <defaultGoal>clean install tomcat7:run-war-only</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>  <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
                            <arguments>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>${tomcat.context}</path>
                    <port>${tomcat.webport}</port>
                    <ajpPort>${tomcat.ajpport}</ajpPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <JAVA_OPTS>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</JAVA_OPTS>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my whole project structure:

```
daniel@DK1L:~/git/GWT2.7MavenEclipse/GWT2.7MavenEclipse$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
├── server
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   └── pl
│           │       └── derp
│           │           └── server
│           │               └── GreetingServiceImpl.java
│           └── resources
│               ├── META-INF
│               │   └── persistence.xml
│               └── pl
│                   └── derp
│                       └── server.gwt.xml
├── shared
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│      └── main
│          ├── java
│          │   └── pl
│          │       └── derp
│          │           ├── shared
│          │           │   └── FieldVerifier.java
│          │           └── web
│          │               ├── GreetingServiceAsync.java
│          │               └── GreetingService.java
│          └── resources
│              └── pl
│                  └── derp
│                      └── shared.gwt.xml
├── war
│   └── WEB-INF
│       └── web.xml
├── web
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── pl
│       │   │       └── derp
│       │   │           └── web
│       │   │               ├── Messages.java
│       │   │               └── parent.java
│       │   ├── resources
│       │   │   └── pl
│       │   │       └── derp
│       │   │           ├── parent.gwt.xml
│       │   │           └── web
│       │   │               ├── Messages_fr.properties
│       │   │               └── Messages.properties
│       │   └── webapp
│       │       ├── META-INF
│       │       │   └── context.xml
│       │       ├── parent.css
│       │       ├── parent.html
│       │       └── WEB-INF
│       │           └── web.xml
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           │   └── pl
│           │       └── derp
│           │           └── web
│           │               └── GwtTestparent.java
│           └── resources
│               └── pl
│                   └── derp
│                       └── parentJUnit.gwt.xml
└── WebContent
    └── META-INF
```

I wonder Where I should put persistence.xml? In what package name, dir and project should I put it?

I use gwt 2.7

Answer (score 0):

If you use a maven structure project, you should put the `persistence.xml` file into the following directory:

```
src/main
  /java
    /com.my.package
      /client
      /shared
      /server
  /resources
    /META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Comment: Yes. But I have 3 projects(`server`,`shared`,`client`) with this structure. All of them all maven submodules of `parent` maven module. Parent module doesn't have files. Should I put it in `server` or `shared` or `client`?

Comment: Folders `server`, `shared` and `client` are not "projects", tthey simply represent the GWT directory structure.
I've edited my answer to include your comment.

Comment: Look at my question again. I've updated with pom.xml of `parent` module and files/folder structure.

Comment: Just saw your update, it's definitely not the standard "maven-GWT" structure I had in mind the first time I read your question...

Comment: Ok. But Can You give me some help?

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with such structure in my GWT projects.
Just being curious, but does this "GWT / maven-multi-modules" structure work, or are you still trying to implement it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88559/discussion-between-masterdany88-and-denis-colliot).

Answer (score 0):

According to that [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/app_dev001.htm#:%7E:text=In%20this%20case%2C%20place%20the,file%20relative%20to%20that%20directory.)

the right place for the persistence.xml would be:

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.
```